# Is the associated graded ring of a normal domain a domain?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian local ring, $\mathrm{gr}(R)$ be its associated graded ring. I know that when $R$ is regular, then $\mathrm{gr}(R)$ is a domain (in fact a polynomial ring). I also know an example where $R$ is a domain but $\mathrm{gr}(R)$ is not: say $R=\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$, the coordinate ring of a nodal curve. However in this example $R$ is not normal (i.e. integrally closed).

> I am wondering if $R$ is normal implies $\mathrm{gr}(R)$ is a domain.

Comment: $R=\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]_{(X,Y,Z)}/(X^2-Y^2Z-Z^3)$ with $\mathrm{gr}(R)=\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/(X^2)$. Maybe a little too complicated, but anyway... we need $\dim R\ge2$.